# Fitting padding within parent for vertical centering

Tags: html, css

I think I'm basically there. I've got a DIV at 200px in height and an inner at 150px. This leaves me 50px for the image caption. I want to then vertically center the text within the remaining 50px.

```css
.captioned {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: solid 4px #000000;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.captioned-inner {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.preview {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.preview-image {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.info {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
}

.info-inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.name {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<div class="captioned">
   <div class="captioned-inner">
      <div class="preview" style="background-color: #DE16C7 !important">
         <img class="preview-image" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
         <div class="info-inner">
            <p class="name">Google</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I hope the code makes sense for what I'm trying to acheive. I'm wondering how I can go about incorporating the padding in the 50px height unless I should vertically center and pad the text but that seems a worse way to do it.

Comment: Don't use padding to center items....there a much better ways including flexbox.

Comment: I'm not using padding for the centering, the padding is for within the main outer box so that the text doesn't touch the edges. The actual image is always the same height so margins suffice for that use @Paulie_D

Comment: @learningtoanimate i edited it again this will work for u, keeping height 200px as you mentioned earlier

Comment: I'll test it today, just working on other elements too @Ac_mmi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `display:flex` and `align-items:center` to vertically align the text

Also as you have given `box-sizing:border-box` in `.captioned` class so it would include the border as well in the 200px height that means

`height of the container + top border + bottom border=200px`

so the height of `.preview` container should be `150px - top border(i.e 4px)=146px` and for `.inner` container it will be `50-4 =46px`;

#### This will work for you.

```css
.captioned {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: solid 4px #000000;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.captioned-inner {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.preview {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 146px;
  width: 100%;
}

.preview-image {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 46px;
}

.info-inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.name {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}
```

```html
<div class="captioned">
  <div class="captioned-inner">
    <div class="preview" style="background-color: #DE16C7 !important">
      <img class="preview-image" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div class="info-inner">
        <p class="name">Google</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't use all of this but it was enough to set the alignment with flex, thank you.